# Remove all chars before ":" in XML

Tags: xml, go

```
 <b:Queues i:nil="true"/>
 <b:ReceivedFrom>VJ</b:ReceivedFrom>
 <b:SpecialGDSName i:nil="true"/>
```

I want to remove all data before ":" including ":"

I want to make like this:

```
<Queues i:nil="true"/>
 <ReceivedFrom>VJ</b:ReceivedFrom>
 <SpecialGDSName i:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: You could unmarshal the xml into a struct and then just marshal it back. Go's `encoding/xml` will by default omit the prefixes. Note however that it will also omit them from the attributes, so if you want to keep the prefixes of the attributes you'll need to use a custom `xml.UnmarshalerAttr`. For example: https://go.dev/play/p/0GbLRdvwgy0

Comment: **Warning**: Removing namespace prefixes effectively changes XML component names in ways that likely will change key associations with namespaces that collectively define the syntax and semantics of an XML document.   Be sure to understand what you're doing and how it will affect interoperability between applications producing or consuming your XML document.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

Run the [XML through an XSLT](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/11/using-xslt-with-go.html) like this, which will drop the namespace associated with those elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could use more specialized templates matching only those b:* elements, and do the same thing with a template to strip the namespace from attributes as well.

Comment: XSLT is a fine way to accomplish this goal (+1), but the goal itself may be [inadvisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366857/rove-all-chars-before-in-xml-in-golang#comment124389095_70366857)

Answer (score 1):

Run the document through the xml [Decoder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder) and [Encoder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Encoder).  Modify the namespace on tokens as needed:

```
func rmns(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) error {
    e := xml.NewEncoder(w)
    defer e.Flush()
    d := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    for {
        t, err := d.RawToken()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        switch e := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            e.Name.Space = ""
            for i, a := range e.Attr {
                if a.Name.Space != "" {
                    e.Attr[i].Name = xml.Name{Local: a.Name.Space + ":" + a.Name.Local}
                }
            }
            t = e
        case xml.EndElement:
            e.Name.Space = ""
            t = e
        }
        err = e.EncodeToken(t)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Example use:

```
var doc = `<doc  >
 <b:Queues i:nil="true"/>
 <b:ReceivedFrom>VJ</b:ReceivedFrom>
 <b:SpecialGDSName i:nil="true"/>
</doc>`
var buf bytes.Buffer
if err := rmns(&buf, strings.NewReader(doc)); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// buf contains the translated document
```

[Run the code on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RCsnI5mZSsR).

Comment: Nice way to implement (+1) in Go, OP's tagged language, but the goal itself may be [inadvisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366857/rove-all-chars-before-in-xml-in-golang#comment124389095_70366857)